# cytoscape.js: highlighting of selected edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

In CytoscapeWeb selected edges and nodes are highlighted by yellow border.
In cytoscape.js we can do so for nodes by using border-width and border-color properties. 
Is it possible to do so for edges?

Answer (score 1):

Glows are overly expensive and so are not supported in Cytoscape.js. You can use any of the documented styles to indicate selection state.